# Spring Security Remember Me not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have spent a day on it but do not understand why `remember_me` in SPring Security is not working. I am only using xml as config with no Java code:

```
<http use-expressions="false" auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" filters="none" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <form-login login-page="/BL/index.html" default-target-url="/BL/main.html"
            authentication-failure-url="/BL/index.html?autherror=true"
            always-use-default-target='true' />
        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/BL/index.html"
            invalidate-session="true" />
        <remember-me data-source-ref="dataSource"
            user-service-ref="jdbcUserService" key="99999989"
            token-validity-seconds="86400" />
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/BL/index.html?autherror=true" />
    </http>
```

In short `index.html` is my login page. When I login, I see a cookie getting created by name `SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE` with value `V2FrblE1Vlk3cFd6ZDIvZnRjdnlIZz09OndOb2h2NmUvdFlZRHJvRFRPV3lheHc9PQ`.

But if I now go back to `index.html` page, it asks me to login again. I still see the same cookie value. What is the error in xml config above? I expect that it shouldn't ask me to login again but should redirect to my main page as I am already logged in.

I see the below log on server. Looks like a request is being sent with user as empty string:

> 14:16:34,031 DEBUG JdbcUserDetailsManager:155 - Query returned no
>   results for user '' 14:16:34,031 DEBUG DaoAuthenticationProvider:131 -
>   User '' not found 14:16:34,031 DEBUG
>   UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:318 - Authentication request
>   failed:
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException:
>   Bad credentials 14:16:34,032 DEBUG
>   UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:319 - Updated
>   SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication 14:16:34,032
>   DEBUG UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:320 - Delegating to
>   authentication failure
>   handlerorg.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler@6011c7cf
>   14:16:34,032 DEBUG PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices:214 -
>   Interactive login attempt was unsuccessful. 14:16:34,032 DEBUG
>   PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices:300 - Cancelling cookie
>   14:16:34,032 DEBUG SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler:67 -
>   Redirecting to /BL/index.html?autherror=true

Comment: which version of spring security do you use?

Comment: was the token stored in the database when the user logged in with this username and password?

Comment: @Ralph Spring-Security 3.0.4

Comment: @Ralph Yes the token is stored in database.

Comment: Your log confuse me: PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices does only have 183 lines, so I do not understand what the two debugmessages are about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spring does not prevent a logged in user from accessing the login page.

To test the RememberMe Provider you need at least two pages (with different login)

- the login page
- a normal page that can only be accessed if the user is logged in.

After your user has this cookie, you can close the browser, open the browser again and then directly access the protected page (the user should not been redirected or forwareded to the login page)

But your log statments show, that you try to login the user via login page, on the other hand you told that you want to use the remember me token. - **For using the Remember Me Cookie, you must not request the login page, but some normal page.**

The RememberMeAuthenticationFilter will (when it try to login) print on of this messages at DEBUG level:

- "SecurityContextHolder populated with remember-me token: ..." (success)
- "SecurityContextHolder not populated with remember-me token, as AuthenticationManager rejected Authentication returned by RememberMeServices..." (fail)

Comment: this is the exact answer i wanted to write. well done!

Comment: @Ralph Thanks. I mis-understood the functionality. Now it explains everything.